# Self hosting Web Api service into Windows Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I am trying to self host a Web Api service inside a windows forms application using the code below

```
namespace MascoteAquarium.Desktop
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/id", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
            {
                server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new frmMainMenu());
        }
    }
}
```

When I try

```
http://localhost:8080/api/*(some-controller)*
```

I receive a *NullReferenceException* at *System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer.ProcessRequestContext(ChannelContext channelContext, RequestContext requestContext)*

Someone know what is happening? Is it possible to self host inside a Win Forms app?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that the *HttpSelfHostServer* object gets lost just before *Application.Run(...)*, which contains the main event loop that keeps your program running. The [**using**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement makes sure that **Dispose** method gets called for the object, in this case *server*, thus making it unavailable for answering requests, resulting in the *NullReferenceException* you are experiencing.

To fix the exception, your code should look like this:

```
...
using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
{
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new frmMainMenu());
}
...
```

Comment: you save me from Scratching my head BIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIG Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to run the WinForms application (or VS if you run the WinForm app from the debugger) with elevated privileges (as Admin), otherwise the self-host will not be allowed to open a port.
2. Make sure no other application is running on port 8080 already